# Electrostatic transfer in wires

Tags: wire, esd, electrostatic

[image]

See illustration above.

I would like to know what happens if there is a wire between the static in the finger and an ESD senstive IC. What happens to the static in the wire or how does it behave in such a situation?

[image]

If you hold this EEG gold cap with huge static in your finger, and the black end is connected to an electrostatic discharge (ESD) sensitive IC, would the static travel in the wire and damage the IC?

[image]

ESD can destroy electronic components like ICs. Usually, its action is in the direct immediate vicinity, like inches away- but what if there is a one meter wire (let's say thin wire) between it and the fingers with static charge? Would the wire induce a huge current that can destroy the ICs or would the charges dissipate in the length of the thin wire?

I'm asking this because I wonder if the long wires in ECG or EEG can protect the ESD-sensitive IC from static in the fingers holding the end of the wire. This is versus just touching the ESD-sensitive IC directly.

Comment: _"induce a huge current"_ Current isn't induced, voltage is. Please draw your proposed setup. The stock image gives no clues.

Comment: For just a wire, copper is a better conductor than air, so I doubt it would make a positive difference to ESD. But if the wire is part of a shielded cable, then there is some capacitance involved. This may be advantageous, but I’d still suggest you have ESD protection on your device.

Comment: pls see edit....

Comment: Please draw the set-up you are considering. The devil is in the detail.

Comment: hey, you've been asked to draw a setup, instead you posted a foto of some wires? What's that about, Samzun?

Comment: I think the "drawing" is pretty clear - it represents an electrostatic discharge from a finger to a wire to an IC.

Comment: You can calculate some equivalent series resistance of a copper wire based on length and diameter.

Comment: In short - Yes, wires conduct electricity (that's what they're designed to do) and if you touch a wire it's the same thing as if you touched the IC directly.

Comment: @JRE that's the new drawing, and it's kind of … good, actually?

Comment: @MarcusMüller:  Oh.  I hadn't checked all the revisions.  Yeah.  The first with just the wires wasn't helpful.  I don't know about good, but at least comprehendable.

Comment: What about earth/ground? What is earthed and what isn't. It makes a massive difference. Draw a proper picture please.

Comment: they are all NOT earthed. There is no particular circuit, just to understand the physics part. Guys. Is it not static is static, it doesnt move? how could static flow through a wire, wont the wire disippate the static charges?

Comment: the "physics part" depends on there being a place for current to flow, so "there's no particular circuit" doesn't work – because then there's also no discharge. And as you notice, current flowing kind of implies things aren't static, so even if the name says "static" the phenomenon isn't.

Comment: `What happens to the static in the wire` ... static what? ... that's like saying `I ate a purple` when talking about eating a purple grape

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough "static" electricity built up on your body, that touching an IC would produce a visible spark... then touching a wire which led to an IC would do the same thing.  That would create two sparks, adding up to the length of the original spark. One at the finger to the wire, and one from the wire to the IC. The current peak would be nearly identical though, unless the wire was also dissipating some energy.

Many physical details are relevant, such as:

- The size of the IC.  Much less damage could be done if the IC was just a single small one, floating in space, versus this "IC" on a board with connections to ground.  The floating IC has no connection to ground, so any spark current would just serve to equalize charge between the finger and the IC, which has very little capacitance by itself.  But a grounded chip would allow nearly infinite charge transfer to take place = more damage to chips.
- The voltage of the static charge / resistance of wire.  If the static charge is only 20 Volts, then it likely is too low to damage anything.  Likewise, if the "wire" had a really high resistance of 20 GΩ, then even a 20 kV charge could at most conduct 20k/20G = 1 nA of current.  This is why anti-static wrist straps use a black plastic "wire"; that wire is really just a very high-value resistor, to slowly and safely bleed off any high voltage charge when it is encountered.
- The characteristics of the wire.  A typical insulated metallic "hookup" wire would present little resistance to a spark.  But if the insulation were removed and twenty meters of it draped around the room, then significant energy would be lost before charge reached the IC.
- All other conceivable physical properties and conditions, like altitude (less air at higher altitudes = lower insulating property = longer sparks.) "Air" constituents (operation in a low-pressure helium/neon atmosphere = plasma = LASER), temperature, presence of ionizing radiation, etc.  The "devil" is in the details!

Static charge is a *localized* imbalance of electrons. i.e., if your finger zaps an IC, then *you* were charged higher than the surroundings.  If someone tosses (an uncharged) coin into the air and you catch it, the moment you touch it, charge will flow from you to the coin to equalize the (now very high) charge (relative to everything else.)  The coin has very little capacitance, so it will not visibly spark when you touch it.  If you then toss this coin to someone else (whom is uncharged), charge will flow to them when they catch it, but not much, because the coin has little capacitance.

Now a circuit board, connected to mains power, includes a neutral and ground wire. These wires connect to the Earth, which is very large and has lots of capacitance; billions more times the capacitance than a human body has.  So when you touch this grounded board, *all* of your charge jumps into the board, making you the same potential as the Earth (and doing the most work on (potential damage to) the board.)

Comment: Did you mean by ground the pcb ground connected to negative terminal of a dc battery without physical connection to earth or ground where there is direct connection to the earth like in ac grounding?

Comment: The USB isolator is probably rated for 2, 4, or 6 thousand volts.  If you have 30 kV of charge on your body (possible when you sit/stand from a plastic chair or drag feet on carpet), then this isn't going to save it.  Just wear an anti-static wrist strap, and clip it to the USB ground (silver shell.)  Then when you sit/stand/shuffle, that charge is gently coupled to ground.  Also use a humidifier - the generation of static electricity needs dry air to work; make the air less dry and static won't form as easily. Be mindful of condensation though (such as on cold windows - don't want mold.)